# Submitting button inside a form selenium + python

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium

I have this form which contains a button with some dynamic value, when I click on it it should add the product to the checkout page.
Here is the html form :

```
    {%for p in product %}
 <div class="single-product">
    <div class="product-f-image">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{p.image_medium}}" alt="">
         <div class="">
       {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <form action="/login/">
       <button class="add-to-cart-link" type="submit"> Add to cart</button>
      </form>
      {%else%}
    <form id="form-id"  action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="add-to-cart-link" type="submit" name="product" value="{{p.id}}" >
<input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{p.name}}">
<input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="{{p.lst_price}}">
    Add to cart</button>
  </form>
     {%endif%}
 <a href="#" class="view-details-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> See details</a>
 </div>
  </div>
 <h2><a href="single-product.html">{{p.id}}</a></h2>
<div class="product-carousel-price">
 <ins>{{p.lst_price}} €</ins>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            {%endfor%}
```

And here is my what I am doing with selenium:

```
bon_commande = self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='product' and @value='37']/parent::form")
bon_commande.submit()
```

And thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to click the submit button:

```
// add some sleep to wait the JS files of page 
// load completely to register click event to the submit button
// otherwise nothing to response to the click 
// (because the `action` of the form is empty.)

self.selenium.sleep(15); // sleep 15 seconds
self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='product' and @value='37']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no error but still, it didn't send me to the page of checkout which mean I think the click button didn't perform ! :/

Comment: Try add some sleep before click the button

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to locate Submit button to submit a form - use **any** element inside form or `form` element itself:

```
self.selenium.find_element_by_id("form-id").submit()

self.selenium.find_element_by_class_name("add-to-cart-link").submit()
```

*Update*

Try to wait until django variable `"{{p.id}}"` is replaced with generated value:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@name='product' and @value='37']"))).submit()
```

Comment: Ok ! this got me to the checkout page but no product added :/ i think we need to pass the id of the product

Comment: Do you need to click something like "Add to cart" button before submitting form? Can you share the sequence of manual steps you need to execute to get required output?

Comment: Sure ! I've got a list of product (e-commerce website), the 'add-to-cart' button contains some element like (id, name, price). When a user click on the button of the desired product its add to the checkout page. Hope I was clear

Comment: So there are many "Add to cart" buttons on page - each inside its own form. And after clicking button new page is opened? Can you share little more HTML?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button with text as **Add to cart** you can use the following line of code :

```
self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form-id']/button[@class='add-to-cart-link' and @name='product']").submit()
#or
self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form-id']/button[@class='add-to-cart-link' and @name='product']").click()
```